# Quill Editor scrolls up slightly when pasting large content in a Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

Here is my editor.vue

I am trying to replicate the auto-grow example on their [playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/#autogrow-height)

I tried to add a scrolling container, and set heights for elements but the issue still persists.

```js
<template>
  <div ref="scrollingContainer" class="scrolling-container">
    <div ref="editorNode" class="editor-node" :style="editorStyle" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Quill from "quill";
export default {
  name: "App",
  props: {
    minHeight: {
      type: String,
      default: "450px",
    },
    scrollable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editorInstance: null,
      editorOpts: {
        modules: {
          toolbar: [
            [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
            ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
          ],
        },
        theme: "snow",
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    editorStyle() {
      var style = "min-height: " + this.minHeight + ";";
      if (this.scrollable) {
        style += "overflow-y:auto;";
        style += "max-height: " + this.minHeight + ";";
      }
      return style;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.editorOpts["scrollingContainer"] = this.$refs.scrollingContainer;
    this.editorInstance = new Quill(this.$refs.editorNode, this.editorOpts);
    // Setup handler for whenever things change inside Quill
    this.$emit("instance-created", this.editorInstance);
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.editor-node {
  height: auto;
}
.scrolling-container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.ql-editor strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ql-editor {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
.ql-editor p {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-block-start: 0px !important;
  margin-block-end: 0px !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
@import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
</style>
```

You can also find a codesandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-skuss?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

If you paste alot of content, after a certain height, the page would scroll up a bit... resulting in a very weird experience.

Edit: The webkit based browsers like chrome's scroll to top issue can be fixed by upgrading quill to 2.0.0-dev.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making clipboard in center and fix its position to avoid it to move with the text:

```
.ql-clipboard {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0px; // fix the width to 0, so large text cannot overflow the div
}
```

Here is the codesandbox for your reference:

https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-cp8jn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1559-1620

Comment: This looks like the solution! Can you add a bit more explanation? I assumed the clipboard is not visible?

Comment: the library will copy the text to clipboard div as well and `.clipboard` class is hidden with left: -100000px but with large text, the width may exceed -100000px and visible to screen for a second and disappear again (after the text visible to textbox) which looks like weird scrolling up effect. the left: 50% is to make the div  always visible and center on screen to avoid invisible <-> visible effect. If you want a more perfect effect without a glimpse of flip, you can set `width: 0px`. updated answer as well.

Comment: That makes sense to me! You saved me a lot of trouble... Also looks like the scrolling container is not necessary

Comment: Hey additional update, the editor jumps to the toolbar whenever I add content after a certain height on webkit based browsers like chrome...

Comment: lol seems like another issue. need to see what's happening

Comment: Funny, because the original issue explained to me was this one, but I couldn't repro that on firefox and figured it was the same issue I mentioned...

Comment: I think the original issue is a slight jumpy (the toolbar jump up as well) and flash effect whenever the large block of text is inserted. It is solved. Therefore, this scroll back to the top is another issue i think.

Comment: @Blaine used very long time to try all the solutions, finally upgrade to 2.0.0-dev4 can solve the scroll to top problem. updated codesandbox. you can test it as well. I think you can open another question for that as well. It is quite a tedious problem, i think lots of people suffering from that.

Comment: Do you want me to open another question on stack overflow? So that this can be marked as the answer? Or should I update the current question?

Comment: up to you. If you can make the title better (include flash effect and scroll effect), it will help others to find the solutions

Comment: I can make another question no problems, do you want to answer that one as well?

Comment: sure. let's see if the community can answer quicker than me lol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633218/quill-scrolls-to-top-on-webkit-based-browsers-like-chrome-after-pasting-content

Comment: You can respond to that, and once again thanks for your help. I looked around quite alot for this.