# Quill scrolls to top on webkit based browsers like chrome, after pasting content larger than certain height

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

This was my main question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571133/quill-editor-scrolls-up-slightly-when-pasting-large-content-in-a-vue-app)

I am trying to replicate the auto-grow example on their [playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/#autogrow-height)

I tried to add a scrolling container, and set heights for elements but

You can also find a codesandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-skuss?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

If you paste alot of content, after a certain height, the page would scroll up to the top of the editor... resulting in a very jarring experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll to top problem with large amount of text cannot even be solved by the [Autogrow example](https://quilljs.com/standalone/autogrow/) in quill.

After some trial and errors, the upcoming 2.0.0 can solve it perfectly.

As of 22-May-2021, the latest version is `2.0.0-dev.4`

```
yarn add quill@2.0.0-dev.4
// or
npm install quill@2.0.0-dev.4
```

The codesandbox example for demostration:

https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-cp8jn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue